# Split large plaintext file into smaller ones on the last whitespace before each 2000th character

Tags: zsh, bsd

Requirement: BSD versions of tools not GNU.

I have a ZSH script that scrapes a weekly newsletter from a website, grabs the main section, converts it into plain text, and saves it to a file. It then further breaks it up the different sections of the newsletter into separate files (file1.txt...) and uploads each of them to a respective dashboard. This allows me to historically sort through information in any given section (manually/visually). The sections also often contain hyperlinks to sources of information. The dashboard has a 2000 character (byte) limit per post. I initially used `split -b 2000 file1.txt a` (file2.txt was then b, and file3.txt was c) The problem with this is that the 2000th character is rarely a space so it often cuts words and URLs into different posts.

So how can I make it split those files on the last whitespace between each 2000th character?

That may also be imperfect, more like:

```
count 2000 characters
backup to last withespace
put everything that came before into a file 
count from that whitespace 2000 more characters
backup to previous whitespace
put everything that came between last split point and this whitespace into next file
loop.
```

until it iterates to the end of the file.

Comment: The loop you describe sounds right, though I have to say that's an interesting dashboard thing you have that didn't support pagination on its own! Can you tell us a bit about that?

Comment: Other than that, you could quite directly implement your loop in python instead of trying to shoehorn a shell into doing it. Is python available?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's a personal discord server. I am using the webhook to post directly into each channel, because of that the bot isn't an actual bot and doesn't benefit from nitro or anything like that

Comment: You would be better off writing this in python or perl.  They both have library modules for fetching URLs, parsing HTML, extracting text and interacting with discord. They both also have functions (e.g. `substr` in perl, or string slicing in python) for extracting small sections of text from larger texts and for literal and/or regex character matching.   BTW, you probably want to break on any whitespace (including unicode whitespace chars if relevant) AND punctuation (expect, perhaps, for hyphens), not just a space character.

Comment: The thing is @cas I already have ALL of those functions written, curl downloads the webpage. I use "from1='<main' to2='/main>'" to extract the main section, html2text converts it to plain text, split separates the files on 2000 Bytes and I have already made the ZSH discord bot that handles the upload. I have been using this bot for a few months. The ONLY feature missing is cleanly splitting the newsletter. The project is 99% done.

Comment: This project actually started as a ZSH discord bot, because I had seen one written in BASH, and wanted to write my own in ZSH. Then once that was done I pondered on what to do with it and came up with archiving the newsletter. That's why I'm trying to use ZSH for all of it, as it is an extension of the bot that I already wrote in ZSH.

Answer (score 0):

Shell languages are pretty good at splitting things into words, as long as you do not need to preserve the exact whitespace from the input (e.g. consecutive spaces can be consolidated to a single space).

The processing can be made a bit easier by looking ahead - for each word, if it'll fit in a file, add it. Otherwise move on to the next file. Line wrapping is similar:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

inFile=$1
fileAsWords=($(<$inFile))

outfileNum=0
outputText=
sep=
lineLen=0
eol=$'\n'
for word in $fileAsWords; do
    if (( ${#outputText} + ${#sep} + ${#word} + ${#eol} > 2000 )); then
        printf -v outfileName out-%04d.txt outfileNum++
        print -r -- $outputText > $outfileName
        outputText=
        sep=
        lineLen=0
    fi
    if (( lineLen > 0 && lineLen + ${#sep} + ${#word} > 80 )); then
        sep=${eol}
        lineLen=0
    fi
    outputText+=${sep}${word}
    (( lineLen += ${#sep} + ${#word} ))
    sep=' '
done
if (( ${#outputText} > 0 )); then
    printf -v outfileName out-%04d.txt outfileNum
    print -r -- $outputText > $outfileName
fi
```

This may still split some items like URLs across files, if those can contain embedded spaces. The set of characters used for splitting can be changed by setting `IFS` (internal field separator) prior to creating the array of words.

Comment: Or just `printf -v outFilename out-%04d.txt outfileNum++` as the arguments for %d are already interpreted as arithmetic expressions, so that would save a round-tripping between text and number. See also `outFilename=out-${(l[4][0])$((outfileNum++))}`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I had used `${(l..)}` for padding in my original version, but thought it looked a bit too cryptic for this post. I also took out `if ((#outputText))` just to avoid having to explain it :-). I didn't know about the `%d` context - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like:

```
process() {
  do-what-you-have-to-do-with-the-chunk $1
}
chunk_size=2000
file=file1.txt

set -o extendedglob # needed for (#cmin,max), ## and (#b)

# contents of the file trimmed of leading and trailing whitespace
text=${${$(<$file)%%[[:space:]]##}##[[:space:]]##}

while (( $#text > chunk_size )); do
  if [[ $text = (#b)(?(#c0,$((chunk_size - 1)))[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]##(*) ]]; then
    process $match[1]
    text=$match[2]
  else
    print -ru2 Text cannot be split
    exit 1
  fi
done
if [[ -n $text ]]; then
  # last chunk
  process $text
done
```

Note that the lengths are computed in terms of number of *character*, not *bytes*. You could `set +o multibyte` to count in bytes, but that would also mean that multibyte spacing characters would then be ignored. In my British locale, most spacing characters are encoded on more than one byte, but they are not the most commonly used. They are:

```
           09 U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
           0A U+000A LINE FEED
           0B U+000B LINE TABULATION
           0C U+000C FORM FEED
           0D U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
           20 U+0020 SPACE
     E1 9A 80 U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
     E2 80 80 U+2000 EN QUAD
     E2 80 81 U+2001 EM QUAD
     E2 80 82 U+2002 EN SPACE
     E2 80 83 U+2003 EM SPACE
     E2 80 84 U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
     E2 80 85 U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
     E2 80 86 U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
     E2 80 88 U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
     E2 80 89 U+2009 THIN SPACE
     E2 80 8A U+200A HAIR SPACE
     E2 80 A8 U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
     E2 80 A9 U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
     E2 81 9F U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
     E3 80 80 U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```